# Filter on prefetch_related in Django

Tags: django, django-1.4

Is there a way of filtering prefetched objects? I need to get the latest() of the prefetched objects but prefetch_related doesn't work if you use latest because the query is changed?

The example here does what I need but I was hoping there's a simpler workaround...

https://github.com/ionelmc/django-prefetch#example

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of Django 1.7, filtering prefetched objects is possible. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974801/487598), and [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: The Django documentation currently seems to suggest otherwise. It says the following, and goes into a bit more depth than this:

"Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query."

It specifically says that calling a method on a prefetched set of data "in fact it hurts performance, since you have done a database query that you haven’t used. So use this feature with caution!"

Comment: You can avoid the additional filter by making use of the `Prefetch` object

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple method which is hardly comparable with those app, but hope you will find it useful:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def latest_book(self):
        return max(self.book_set.all(), key=lambda book: book.created)

authors = Author.objects.prefetch_related('book_set')
authors[0].latest_book() #  what you wanted
```

Comment: I tested this and it seems to generate the same queries as the naive loop... I don't think you can use select_related on a reverse relation

Comment: I am sorry - of course it should be prefetch_related (I edited my answer). Using this hole set with all() is prefetched and iterating it shouldn't hit database.

Comment: How can I filter using lambda?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be done in this way :

```
authors=Author.objects.prefetch_related('book_set')
```

If you want to filter by an attribute(name) present in Author model you can simply filter it by writing:

```
authors.filter(name='your_value')
```

But if you want to apply filter on the Books model you have to write the following way:

```
authors.filter(book__created__gt='your_date')
```

This will filter all the books that have create date(created attribute in the Book module) greater than your date.

Comment: This doesn't work: filter or get will create a query and does not use the prefetched objects