# Why does django's prefetch_related() only work with all() and not filter()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, prefetch

suppose I have this model:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('PhotoAlbum')
    format = models.IntegerField()
```

Now if I want to look at a subset of photos in a subset of albums efficiently. I do it something like this:

```
someAlbums = PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(author="Davey Jones").prefetch_related("photo_set")
for a in someAlbums:
    somePhotos = a.photo_set.all()
```

This does only two queries, which is what I expect (one to get the albums, and then one like `SELECT * IN photos WHERE photoalbum_id IN ().

Everything is great.

But if I do this:

```
someAlbums = PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(author="Davey Jones").prefetch_related("photo_set")
for a in someAlbums:
    somePhotos = a.photo_set.filter(format=1)
```

Then it does a ton of queries with `WHERE format = 1`! Am I doing something wrong or is django not smart enough to realise it has already fetched all the photos and can filter them in python? I swear I read somewhere in the documentation that it is supposed to do that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter on prefetch\_related in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915319/filter-on-prefetch-related-in-django)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

In Django 1.6 and earlier, it is not possible to avoid the extra queries. The `prefetch_related` call effectively caches the results of `a.photoset.all()` for every album in the queryset. However, `a.photoset.filter(format=1)` is a different queryset, so you will generate an extra query for every album.

This is explained in the  [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) docs. The `filter(format=1)` is equivalent to `filter(spicy=True)`.

Note that you could reduce the number or queries by filtering the photos in python instead:

```
someAlbums = PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(author="Davey Jones").prefetch_related("photo_set")
for a in someAlbums:
    somePhotos = [p for p in a.photo_set.all() if p.format == 1]
```

In Django 1.7, there is a [`Prefetch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object that allows you to control the behaviour of `prefetch_related`.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

someAlbums = PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(author="Davey Jones").prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "photo_set",
        queryset=Photo.objects.filter(format=1),
        to_attr="some_photos"
    )
)
for a in someAlbums:
    somePhotos = a.some_photos
```

For more examples of how to use the `Prefetch` object, see the [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) docs.

Answer (score 11):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> ...as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query. So, if you write the following:
>
> `pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related('toppings')`
> `[list(pizza.toppings.filter(spicy=True)) for pizza in pizzas]`
>
> ...then the fact that pizza.toppings.all() has been prefetched will not help you - in fact it hurts performance, since you have done a database query that you haven't used. So use this feature with caution!

In your case, "a.photo_set.filter(format=1)" is treated like a fresh query.

In addition, "photo_set" is a reverse lookup - implemented via a different manager altogether.

Comment: `photo_set` can be prefetched, as well, with `.prefetch_related('photo_set')`. But order matters, as you have explained.