# Django api returning model ID instead of model's title

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im new to django When I **make a api call** it shows **model.id** but I wanted **model.title**[image]

As we can see that **my title is 1** but I wanted the **title of the model**not ID

Model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def description_as_list(self):
        return self.description.split('\n')

class Comment(models.Model):
    title=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comments=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, id):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    comments=posts.comment_set.all()
    forms=CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.title = posts
            print comment
            comment.save()
        else:
          print form.errors
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, "detail_post.html", {'forms':forms,'posts': posts,'comments':comments})
```

serializer.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('title','comments')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','description','pub_date')
```

How can I achieve the title of the blog name instead of just ID

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You `Comment`s `title` property is a foreign key. `title=models.ForeignKey(Post)`.
That's why your're getting a number.

Comment: What you need to do is get the `Post` object and get it's `title`.

Comment: `fields = ('title__title', 'comments')`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Does that fire another DB query or should a prefetch be perfomed before?

Comment: @Coeus Well first you should change `Comment`s `title` to `post` so it's actually named after what it is. Then in the view when you get the comments with `posts.comment_set.all()` you should ensure that this prefetches the `Post` data too so you don't fire unneeded DB queries. I'll try to Google around a bit. Then do what @BurhanKhalid said. Put the 'title__title' ('post__title' after you change if you change.) in the comment seralizer.

Comment: In the view you could get the comments like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974801/887828). This way you don't run unnecessary DB queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    title = serializers.CharField(source="title.title", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('title','comments')
```

Comment: By doing so title field is completely, only the comments fields is shown

Comment: Typo, should be source="title.title".

Comment: Still Works in Django 3.1!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the post's `title` instead of the `id` from the `CommentSerializer`, you'll need to define explicitly the field in the `CommentSerializer` and use a [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).