# django queryset from other's queryset manytomany

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-filter

What's the most efficient way to get all the records from a ManyToMany into a queryset?

To give an example, If I have a model named `Events` that has a ManyToMany to a model named `Items` and I have a queryset that contains `Events`. How do I get the queryset that contains all the `Items` that all the `Events` in the queryset point on?

If it was a single event, it would be: `Events.items.all()`. but this is a queryset so I can't do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Items.filter(event_set__in=some_events_qs)` will do it. This uses a lazily evaluated nested query - but see the performance considerations [noted in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in).

This might return dupes if an `Item` belongs to more than one event in the initial queryset, I can never remember how that works. If so, `.distinct()` will clean it up but can also have a performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for minimizing the number of DB hits for fetching related objects:

> This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using `select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>   relationships that are supported by `select_related`.

Your query will look:

```
events = events.objects.all().prefetch_related('items')
```

And the related objects:

```
items = [e.items.all() for e in events]
```

If `event` were a single object, it would look:

```
event = events.objects.get(id=id).prefetch_related('items')
# items related to that event
items = event.items.all()
```

Comment: Hi moses, thanks but I already know prefetch_related() its not exactly what I'm asking.. `items = [e.items.all() for e in events]` will give me the items, but I'm looking for a *queryset of items*, not a list (eg I want to apply other filters on it before fetching them etc.). Also I may be wrong here but I doubt its the most efficient way..

Comment: Then you may have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973929/why-does-djangos-prefetch-related-only-work-with-all-and-not-filter). You can filter if you get the related object directly without using `prefetch_related`