# Django - Query using .0. does not work whilst using .first(). creates duplicate queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a need to only get one record from a queryset_set. (as it only returns 1. so I have used .0 or .first() normally.

However at the moment when I use .0 I do not get any data. when I use .first() I get duplicated queries (despite the prefetch)

I have tried to use a sub query but from the samples ive seen I am unable to interpret it to suit my needs.

The query which generates duplicate when using first but nothing when using 0

```
circuits = SiteCircuits.objects.all() \
                        .exclude(circuit__decommissioned=True) \
                        .select_related('site') \
                        .select_related('circuit') \
                        .prefetch_related(
                            Prefetch(
                            'circuit__devicecircuitsubnets_set',
                            queryset=DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.all().select_related('subnet')
                            ) \
                        ) \
```

in the template:

```
{% for item in circuits  %}
    {{ item.circuit.devicecircuitsubnets_set.0.subnet }}{{ item.circuit.devicecircuitsubnets_set.0.mask }}
    ...
```

models:

```
class Circuit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name")
    order_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Order No")
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Reference No")
    expected_install_date = models.DateField()
    install_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class SiteCircuits(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    site_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="How many sites circuit is used at?", blank=True, null=True)
    active_link = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Active Link?")

class Device(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, verbose_name="Site device belongs to", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Subnet(models.Model):     
    subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', \
                                        verbose_name="Subnet", blank=True, null=True)
    mask = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name="Mask", \

class DeviceCircuitSubnets(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subnet = models.ForeignKey(Subnet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

sample output in console:

```
>>> circuits[100].circuit.devicecircuitsubnets_set.first().subnet.subnet
'10.10.10.4'
>>> circuits[100].circuit.devicecircuitsubnets_set.all()[0].subnet.subnet
'10.10.10.4'
>>>
```

Comment: does anyone have any ideas on this one, I have the issues on two queries now, using .first shows data but creates duplicates. using .0 does not show any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
I'm not sure why your query is failing, but [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) say you need to be careful in the order in which prefetch is called. My next guess would be to  try removing all prefetching apart from that which is absolutely necessary. Sorry it's not expert advice, I'm just muddling along myself. Also if you are using Django 1.11 onwards, you could re-write the query as below, as you are only interested in the first subnet/mask object per SiteCircuit.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

subnet = Subquery(
    DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(circuit_id=OuterRef(
        'circuit_id')).values('subnet__subnet')[:1])
mask = Subquery(
    DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(circuit_id=OuterRef(
        'circuit_id')).values('subnet__mask')[:1])

circuits = SiteCircuits.objects.filter(
    circuit__decommissioned=False
).annotate(
    circuit_subnet=subnet,
    cicuit_mask=mask
).select_related(
    'site'
).select_related(
    'circuit'
)
```

You could then access this by:

```
{% for item in circuits  %}
    {{ item.circuit_subnet }}{{ item.circuit_mask }}
...
```

You shouldn't need to call `prefetch_related` on relationships which aren't many-to-many or one-to-many. For many-to-one and one-to-one relationships you should use `select_related` instead. E.g. you should use `.select_related('circuit__circuit_type')` rather than `.prefetch_related('circuit__circuit_type')` assuming that `circuit_type` is not a many to many field.

== From OP ==
Debug toolbar output:

```
SELECT "config_devicecircuitsubnets"."id", "config_devicecircuitsubnets"."device_id", "config_devicecircuitsubnets"."circuit_id", "config_devicecircuitsubnets"."subnet_id", "config_subnet"."id", "config_subnet"."subnet", "config_subnet"."mask", "config_subnet"."subnet_type_id" FROM "config_devicecircuitsubnets" INNER JOIN "circuits_circuit" ON ("config_devicecircuitsubnets"."circuit_id" = "circuits_circuit"."id") INNER JOIN "config_subnet" ON ("config_devicecircuitsubnets"."subnet_id" = "config_subnet"."id") WHERE (NOT ("circuits_circuit"."decommissioned" = 'True' AND "circuits_circuit"."decommissioned" IS NOT NULL) AND "config_devicecircuitsubnets"."circuit_id" = '339') ORDER BY "config_devicecircuitsubnets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Duplicated 526 times.
```

this line is highlighted in debug toolbar:

```
{{ item.circuit.devicecircuitsubnets_set.first.subnet }}{{ item.circuit.devicecircuitsubnets_set.first.mask }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, however the duplicate queries are based on devicecircuitsubnets_set not sitecircuits_set. the above doesn't include, devicecircuitsubnets_set

Comment: Ah I see you've updated the question. The things that stand out as fishy to me: a) calling select_related on 'circuits' even though you're prefetching a subquery of it, so that may not be necessary, b) that you're calling select_related('subnet') which is both the class name and an attribute. Would put my mind at rest to see .filter(circuit__decommissioned=False) too :-) Good luck.

Comment: added the filter, to the query, no difference. ive also added the debug toolbar output

Comment: I added an example using Subquery and OuterRef, if you're using Django 1.11 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the internals, but I suspect that `first()` generates extra queries for similar reasons that `filter()` does. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973929/why-does-djangos-prefetch-related-only-work-with-all-and-not-filter/12974801#12974801) for more info.

For the second part of your question about why does `.0` not return any results - your models and code are so complicated that I can't understand them. You might get a better response if you provided a simpler example (including the models) which reproduced the problem.

Comment: ive rescued the query to just the problem and the provided sample models, is there a equlivielnt of doing .0 in console? Ive used .all()[0] but I don't thing thats the same?

Comment: `.all()[0]` in Python is equivalent to `.all.0` in the the template.

Comment: ok using .all.0 has fixed the issue, I no longer have 500+ duplicates!