# How to apply an arbitrary filter on a specific chained prefetch_related() within Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, prefetch

I'm trying to optimize the fired queries of an API. I have four models namely User, Content, Rating, and UserRating with some relations to each other. I want the respective API returns all of the existing contents alongside their rating count as well as the score given by a specific user to that.

I used to do something like this: `Content.objects.all()` as a queryset, but I realized that in the case of having a huge amount of data tons of queries will be fired. So I've done some efforts to optimize the fired queries using `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()`. However, I'm dealing with an extra python searching, that I hope to remove that, using a controlled `prefetch_related()` — applying a filter just for a specific `prefetch` in a nested `prefetch` and `select`.

Here are my models:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Rating(models.Model):
    count = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.OneToOneField(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    rating = models.ForeignKey(
        Rating, related_name="user_ratings", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "rating"]
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```py
contents = (
    Content.objects.select_related("rating")
    .prefetch_related("rating__user_ratings")
    .prefetch_related("rating__user_ratings__user")
)

for c in contents:  # serializer like
    user_rating = c.rating.user_ratings.all()
    for u in user_rating:  # how to remove this dummy search?
        if u.user_id == 1:
            print(u.score)
```

Queries:

```
(1) SELECT "bitpin_content"."id", "bitpin_content"."title", "bitpin_rating"."id", "bitpin_rating"."count", "bitpin_rating"."content_id" FROM "bitpin_content" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bitpin_rating" ON ("bitpin_content"."id" = "bitpin_rating"."content_id"); args=(); alias=default
(2) SELECT "bitpin_userrating"."id", "bitpin_userrating"."user_id", "bitpin_userrating"."score", "bitpin_userrating"."rating_id" FROM "bitpin_userrating" WHERE "bitpin_userrating"."rating_id" IN (1, 2); args=(1, 2); alias=default
(3) SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."password", "users_user"."last_login", "users_user"."is_superuser", "users_user"."first_name", "users_user"."last_name", "users_user"."email", "users_user"."is_staff", "users_user"."is_active", "users_user"."date_joined", "users_user"."user_name" FROM "users_user" WHERE "users_user"."id" IN (1, 4); args=(1, 4); alias=default
```

As you can see on the above fired queries I've only three queries rather than too many queries which were happening in the past. However, I guess I can remove the python searching (the second `for` loop) using a filter on my latest query — `users_user"."id" IN (1,)` instead. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973929/why-does-djangos-prefetch-related-only-work-with-all-and-not-filter/12974801#12974801) and my efforts, I couldn't apply a `.filter(rating__user_ratings__user_id=1)` on the third query. Actually, I couldn't match my problem using `Prefetch(..., queryset=...)` instance given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974801/3702377).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Prefetch object:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects

Try this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

contents = Content.objects.select_related("rating").prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "rating__user_ratings",
        queryset=UserRating.objects.filter(user__id=1),
        to_attr="user_rating_number_1",
    )
)

for c in contents:  # serializer like
    print(c.rating.user_rating_number_1[0].score)
```

Comment: I ran the mentioned code snippet, however, the result is wrong as it brings the user's rating with different IDs as well. As well as this, the query is fired in each iteration.

Comment: I think the `.all()` should be changed to `.filter(user__id=1)`. In this case, the result would be right. But the queries are repeated.

Comment: No. You should use `.all()` in this case, because filtering is done in `Prefetch` object. I updated the code. What `print(user_rating)` prints?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'` So I updated your answer if you don't mind. Now, it works well. Thank you for your instant response. Actually, my major mistake was using `.filter(user_id)` whereas I should have used `.filter(user__id)` as you mentioned.