# Django filter on prefetch related queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm using **Django 2.2**

I have many reverse related models to the `User` model and I want to get count from each model with different filters.

For example, I have a `Relations` model like

```
status = (
  ('Active', 'active')
  ('Inactive', 'inactive')
)

class Relation(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='relation')
  status = models.CharField(choices=status, default=ACTIVE)
```

Now I want to get the count and the queryset for each status separately for the user. For that I have defined the model methods inside the `User` model

```
def get_relation():
  return self.relation.all()

def get_active_relation(self):
  return self.relation().filter(status='active')

def get_inactive_relation():
  return self.relation().filter(status='inactive')

def get_active_count():
  return self.get_active_relation().count()

def get_inactive_count():
  return self.get_inactive_relaiton().count()
```

I have the user object as

```
user = User.objects.prefetch_related(
  'relation'
).get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Now when I get the count, it executes an extra query for that

```
user.get_active_count()
```

**How can I filter on the `prefetch_related` objects?**

I found a use of `lambda` to get the `max` value from the prefetch_related in another SOF answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12609454/3719167

Is it possible to use `lambda` to filter the queryset as well?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), you can't filter already cached objects.  However, you can filter them out at the time of getting the object using [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch). It is work in django 3.1 too. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk).prefetch_related(
  Prefetch('relation', queryset=Relation.objects.filter(status='active'))
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried filtering on the attributes of the relation?

```
user = User.objects.prefetch_related(
    'relation'
).filter(
    relation__status='active'
).get(pk=request.user.pk)
```